# Failed network lookup

Tags: networking, kubuntu, proxy, firewall

I'm running Kubuntu 12.10. I am having three networking problems that I think might actually have a common cause, even though they are in apparently unrelated areas.  I had them in 12.04 also:

1. When viewing a number of different videos -- but not YouTube -- I get the message `VE_FMS_CONNECT_FAILED`, which says that the video is not currently available.
2. The `launchpad-getkeys` program isn't able to find the keys because it can't do the nslookup for the keyserver URL (and which URL it is doesn't matter).  If I use the `-k` option with the IP address of the keyserver, however, it works.
3. The program `youtube-dl` gives `url-open` errors with this command:

   youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqGRROao5-M

However, if I precede the command with `http_proxy` like this:

```
http_proxy="72.64.146.135:8080"  youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqGRROao5-M
```

it works.  (I know nothing about that IP address; I just copied it from a posted example.)

Two common elements of these examples are:

1. They only strike a few users, not all.
2. They all involve the failure of some network lookup.

Two causes that have been suggested are (a) firewall interception, or (b) proxy misconfiguration.  However, **ufw** tells me that the firewall is inactive, and Network Settings / Proxy tells me that there's no proxy.

I was trying to come up with a more informative title for this thread, but wasn't able to.

Comment: What DNS server do you use? Is the server working correctly when you encounter those errors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and couldn't get videos on the channel 4 website (e.g. http://www.channel4.com/news/catch-up or 4od) to work, and got the same VE_FMS_CONNECT_FAILED error message. I tried this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/ppa-hal
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hal
```

Which worked for me. See [here](http://blog.terranux.net/2014/04/how-to-get-4od-to-work-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/)